# sqlite raw query with inner join and content provider failing to filter by WHERE clause

Tags: sqlite, inner-join, android-contentprovider

I am using a content provider with a multi-table sqlite database. Some of the tables have a relationship to one another of one to many. One table lists the entities and the second table lists the activities, with a reference to the entity by way of the "foreign key" which is the ID of the entity. I don't use an actual "foreign key" but this is how I keep track.

Here are my database tables:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ENTITY = "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE_ENTITY +  "  ( " + ENTITY_KEY_ID + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + NAME + " TEXT, " +  DATE_OBTAINED +  " TEXT, " +  PROFILE_IMAGE + " TEXT, " + QUALITY1 + " TEXT, "  + QUALITY2 +  " TEXT, " +  QUALITY3 + " TEXT, " + " )" ;

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ACTIVE_ENTITIES = "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE_ACTIVE_ENTITIES + "  ( " +  ACTIVE_ENTITY_KEY_ID  + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + TABLE_ENTITY_KEY_ID + " INTEGER, " + NAME  + " TEXT, " +  DATE  +  " TEXT, " + ACTIVITY1  + " TEXT, " +  ACTIVITY2  + " TEXT, "  + ACTIVITY3 + " TEXT, " + ACTIVITY4 +  ...  + "  )" ;
```

So I want to query the results of a particular Entity and get the most recent Activities.  I attempted an inner join on the ENTITY_KEY_ID which is equivalent to the TABLE_ENTITY_KEY_ID in the Activities Table.

This is my content provider query:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] strings, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
      db = hdb.getWritableDatabase();
    int uriType = uriMatcher.match(uri);
     Cursor cursor = null
     case TABLE_ENTITY_JOIN_TABLE_ACTIVE_ENTITIES_ID:
            if (uri != null) {
                String[] args = {uri.getLastPathSegment()

                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  table_entity.NAME, date_obtained, profile_image, quality1, quality2,  quality3, table_active_entities.activity1, table_active_entities.activity2 " +  " FROM table_entity, table_active_entities " + " ON ENTITY_KEY_ID = table_entity_key_id " + " WHERE ENTITY_KEY_ID=?", args);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri");
    }
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

This is where I call the query from my activity :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hermit_page);


    getInfoIntent = getIntent();

    uri = getInfoIntent.getParcelableExtra(MyProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0,null,this);

    action = Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA;
    EntityDataFilter = MyDatabaseHelper.ENTITY_KEY_ID + " = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();

    long id = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContentUris.withAppendedId(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI_TABLE_ENTITY_JOIN_TABLE_ACTIVE_ENTITIES, id),null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabaseHelper.NAME));
        hImage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabaseHelper.PROFILE_IMAGE));
      ...
        cursor.close();
    }
```

The issue I am having is the WHERE clause which selects the ID is not pulling up the rows.  I am either getting the result of the first ID of the ENTITY table if I put cursor.moveToFirst() or I am getting the last ID of the ENTITY table if I put cursor.moveToLast().  I am not getting the info from the join only from the ENTITY TABLE.  It does not correlate to which ENTITY_ID is actually selected. So it seems the WHERE clause is not filtering by ID.  I tried adding parameters to the query statement within the activity(using the EntityDataFilter string) , but this did not produce any difference in results.  I also tried writing the select query as a string initially then plugging the string in the content provider query like : cursor.db.RawQuery(MyStringQuery,args) but this did not work either. I am tracking the output by looking at the TextView results in my activity. Your help is greatly appreciated if you understand why it is giving these results and how I can better write the statement to get the results that I want.  Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why are you using a content provider? Does a plain query work?

Comment: I didnt try a plain query. I use  the content provider because it is already in place and being used by other  activities. Also for future network calls I thought it would be helpful to have. Let me try that and see if I can get it to work.